# Select from array EF, send whole array to server first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, npgsql

I want to do a query that basically looks like this with EF

```
SELECT 
   X.*
  ,(SELECT myval from mytable where timestamp <= X.timestamp limit 1) 
FROM (VALUES ('2010-1-1'), ('2012-1-1')) AS X(timestamp)
```

I have something which functionally does this and looks like this:

```
new DateTime[]{ new DateTime(2010,1,1),new DateTime(2012,1,1) }
    .AsQueryable()//I thought this might make it send the array as part of the query but it doesn't.
    .Select(x => new
        {
            MyVal = ctx.MyTable.Where(t => t.Timestamp <= x.Timestamp).Select(t=>t.MyVal).FirstOrDefault(),
            x.Timestamp
        });
```

This executes two queries as the enumerable is executed in C# and a seperate query is generated for each date selected. This isn't ideal as if there are a lot of values in my list this will generate a silly number of queries when one would do fine.

**Is there a way to instruct EF/restructure the query to send the whole array to SQL** (rather than enumerating it in C#)? I don't really mind if it uses a values clause or something else.

Comment: If performance is critical, try use **stored procedures**?

Comment: I could probably do this with a stored proc but that's a bit heavy handed for what I'm after. It also basically removes any benefit to using EF.

Comment: won't .ToList() do exactly that? this does sound like an issue of deferred execution.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro im not sure I understand what you mean? If i .ToList this I will get two seperate SQL queries (which is exactly what im trying to avoid)

Comment: You need to rewrite your query to make the selection from the context the first thing and join it with the date array

Comment: .Contains **should** translate into an IN clause, which would be one query. I'm not quite sure how you call this code and how this would result in two db calls, but this does not sound right.

Comment: I just noticed: you do the db call within the select clause, which will be translated into a loop by the compiler, so the query will be executed multiple times. however, since you do a <= comparison each time, you could just take those of the maximum and (if necessary) break down further in memory.

Comment: @HaithamShaddad yes im sure if I started with the database it would send the array to SQL, however I cant think of any syntax which would achieve this as I really need a sub-select. Any changing of order I can think of would not generate such a sub-select.